# Moving to Next User in Pagination after Submit Button is Clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I know this question has been asked several times, but there is one thing that I cannot follow. I am trying to move to the next user in my Kaminari pagination after a form is submitted. I have the code working where it will increment the page, but there's currently no conditional statement to keep it from stopping until the form has been submitted:

```
<%= f.submit "Submit Score", class: "btn btn-default" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href="?page=<%=@users.current_page+1 %>"
</script>
```

Here I have my f.submit button and below it is the code that increments the counter. Right now, however, nothing is stopping the incrementing, so when I refresh the page, the counter scrolls until the last user has been reached. I have tried using hidden_tags and flags to add to the conditional if-statement, but nothing is working correctly. I just feel like there is a very simple solution, but I have been messing with my code for a couple hours now, so I am at a loss. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you are submitting your form through a `post` action. So, why don't to redirect from that controller `action`?

Comment: Because from research it seems easier to do it in the View, since my controller does not know paginate, what page I'm on, etc. I originally tried that, but I've found this one works exactly how I want it to, I just don't have a conditional statement to stop it.